# Reduce column height in a multiple plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid

I can create 3 plots and then merge them within the same figure with the following code :

```
p1 <- qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars)
p2 <- p1
p3 <- p1 + theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank())


plot_grid(p1,p2,p3, align = "v",ncol=3)
```

Then I get :

[image]

And and wondered if someone knew if it was possible to reduce the column height ratio of each column independently within the multiplot ? and Get something like :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making use of `patchwork` one option to achieve your desired result may look like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars)
p2 <- p1
p3 <- p1 + theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank())

pp1 <- p1
pp2 <- plot_spacer() / p2 + plot_layout(heights = c(1, 3))
pp3 <- plot_spacer() / p3 + plot_layout(heights = c(1, 1))

pp1 + pp2 + pp3
```

[image]

Comment: can I modify the ratio myself ? for instance if I want that p2 is 3/4 of p1 ?

Comment: For sure. I just made an edit. What I would do is to first set up the plots for each column separately which also makes the code a bit cleaner. Thereby you could use plot_layout to set the relative heights. Afterwards you could glue the column plots together.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach using patchwork:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)


p1 <- qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars)
p2 <- p1
p3 <- p1 + theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank())

design <- 
  "1##
   12#
   123"

p1 + p2 + p3 + plot_layout(design = design)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>